# Client Side filtering of Dictionaries to get unique value

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

In Firestore in the chats Collection,there are several documents as such:

Document1:
receiverID: "Leo"
message: "Hello"
...

Document2:
receiverID: "Peter"
message: "Thank you for helping me"
...

Document 3:
receiverID: "Leo"
message: "My pleasure to help u in stack overflow"

As I am creating an inbox, currently it is showing me a collection view of users such as "Leo","Peter","Leo". I want to display only unique Users such as Leo and Peter in my Inbox, how do I do client side filtering to achieve the results?

Below are my code in InboxViewController

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return chats.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! InboxCollectionViewCell
    cell.inboxMessage.text = chats[indexPath.row].receiverID
    return cell
}


func loadPosts() {
    let senderIDNumber = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let chatsRef = db.collection("chats")
    chatsRef.whereField("senderID", isEqualTo: senderIDNumber!)
        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            for document in documents {
                let messageText = document.data()["message"] as? String
                let senderIDNumber = document.data()["senderID"] as? String
                let receiverIDNumber = document.data()["receiverID"] as? String
                let timestamp = document.data()["timestamp"] as? String
                let conversationsCounter = document.data()["conversationsCounter"] as? Int
                let chat = Chat(messageTextString: messageText!, senderIDNumber: senderIDNumber!, receiverIDNumber: receiverIDNumber!, timeStampString: timestamp!, conversationsCounterInt: conversationsCounter!)
                self.chats.append(chat)
                print(self.chats)
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
    }
}

}
```

Currently, I am getting this in my Inbox:
Leo
Peter 
Leo

I only want to see the name 
Leo
Peter
By removing duplicates.

Comment: check value exit or not in model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check receiveid exist or not in chat

```
if chats.contains(where: { $0. receiverIDNumber == receiverIDNumber }) {
    {
    }else{
    let chat = Chat(messageTextString: messageText!, senderIDNumber: senderIDNumber!, receiverIDNumber: receiverIDNumber!, timeStampString: timestamp!, conversationsCounterInt: conversationsCounter!)
            self.chats.append(chat)
    }
```